# How to hold multiple references to different elements inside a container?

Tags: rust

Consider this simple example: Having `v: Vec<Vec<i32>>` I want to add `v[1]` to `v[0]`.

I'm not even considering sacrificing performance, so cloning any of the vectors is not an option. Thus, no matter how exactly we are going to implement the addition of the vectors, we would need simultaneous references inside `v`: `&mut v[0]` and `&v[1]`. Obviously the problem here is that indexing borrows `v` and indexing in mutable context borrows `v` mutably so the borrow checker would not allow this.

This example leads to a more general problem: how can we hold simultaneous references to *different* elements of a container if all methods that return (mutable) references to elements (mutably) borrow the container itself?

Note that I do understand the origin of the problem and why in compile time the borrow checker cannot see that we are referencing different elements. The question is how do we tell the compiler we are doing the right thing without sacrificing performance and/or safety?

Currently I'm aware of 3 possible solutions without a noticeable performance overhead:

1. `slice::split_at_mut` is a decent workaround but unfortunately works only for sequential/slice-like containers. Note that this function utilizes unsafe code in the implementation.
2. Using iterators: yes, we can hold simultaneous references returned from an iterator, but in many cases using an iterator is not correct, for example, `map: HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>` and I again want to add `map[1]` to `map[0]`.  Note that (to my knowledge) iterators also use unsafe code (directly or indirectly).
3. And finally the solution that works for every container: `RefCell<T>`, that is, wrapping elements of containers in a `RefCell`. (Well, or `Cell<T>` in some cases). There are two problems with this one though. The first is the slight performance overhead for runtime borrow checking. The second one is that if, for example, I'm writing a function which returns a container, I would either have to make the caller use my `RefCell`-wrapped container or have the whole container essentially copied in order to remove the `RefCell` wrapping (Is there a way to unwrap a `RefCell` inside a container for free?) And yet again, `RefCell` uses unsafe code.

All of these solutions use unsafe code. Is it really the only way? I'm also quite sure there is a solution that uses unsafe code directly, but as a beginner I'm a little afraid to delve into unsafe Rust yet. Though, if it happens to be a good solution, please point me to the topics I would need to study.

Are there any other solutions and which one is more practical? Please correct me wherever I don't understand something or understand it wrong.

**Edit:** As Sven Marnach pointed out, my question is too broad, so I'm narrowing the problem down.
I have a `map: HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>` and I want to assign `map[0] + map[1]` (element-wise addition) to `map[0]` with zero performance overhead. Here, repetitive indexing as suggested by matiu would not be optimal because it would involve multiple searches on the same key. So, is it possible? If not, what is the best solution for this case?

Comment: Don't worry too much about `unsafe` in the background. If you don't need to wrap it in `unsafe`, it is safe to use.

Comment: If you implement data structures in Rust, chances are you need unsafe code to get optimal performance, or in many cases to make them work at all. All collections in the standard library extensively use unsafe code, and mutable iterators over _any_ collection can only be implemented using unsafe code. There is nothing wrong with this. The important point is that the external API is safe. Whether the API internally uses unsafe code is an implementation detail you don't need to worry about. It doesn't matter for the user of the safe API.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for the QA format on Stack Overflow. It's rather broad, and contains a lot of hypothetical assumptions – we can't have _any_ performance overhead, not even `RefCell`, it needs to work for _all_ collections etc. SO works best for concrete, practical problems, and if the combination of these assumptions should really occur in a practical problem, then hey, it's really an extremely exceptional case, so let's use some unsafe code.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be afraid to use functions just because they are implemented with `unsafe`. `unsafe` does not mean that the code is unsafe, it means that the code cannot be proven to be safe automatically by the simple rules the compilers knows about. In a well tested, well maintained, and well reviewed library (and especially in the standard library), `unsafe` behind the scene are not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

So the goal is to overwrite vec[0] with vec[0] + vec[1] ?

I think the trick is to use indexes into the Vec, instead of holding the references open.

Does this meet the goal ?

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec = vec![
        vec![1, 2, 3],
        vec![10, 20, 30],
    ];
    let ln = vec[0].len();
    for i in 0..ln {
        vec[0][i] += vec[1][i];
    }
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea1900726ff07b5d2bd0ad39f15e1bba

---

I also wanted to test if doing it in place was actually faster than creating a new array. "Perhaps the compiler is smart enough to do internal memory re-use" I thought. Turns out the compiler is not that smart.

The for loop with indexes is the fastest way.

Code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=1d57a0e5bbb21b3bb87dfc5a7735335f

Results (on my laptop):

```
running 7 tests
test bench_create_new_array   ... bench:         230 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_for_indexes        ... bench:         174 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_new_array_borrow   ... bench:         231 ns/iter (+/- 0)
test bench_to_owned1          ... bench:       1,097 ns/iter (+/- 4)
test bench_to_owned_in_place  ... bench:         240 ns/iter (+/- 1)
test bench_to_owned_in_place2 ... bench:       1,080 ns/iter (+/- 159)
test bench_to_owned_in_place3 ... bench:       1,037 ns/iter (+/- 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, that does solve my first problem but as I explain in the edit that is not the real problem I've encountered which raised the whole question. I'm sorry for misleading you.