# immutable and mutable reference needed for object inside struct

Tags: rust

So the setup is a function on a struct that mutates some interior values (hence passed in &mut self). I'm running into a situation where I believe because I'm using a loop - rust tries to take an immutable reference to field of self, which is already taken mutably upfront

```
node_content: HashMap<Id, Node<T>>;

pub fn set_val(&mut self,..) {
   for id in self.node_content.iter() {
      self.some_function();
}
...
for id in list {
   node = self.node_content.get_mut(id).unwrap();
   
   params=Vec::new()
   for v in node.upstream_nodes() {
        new_node = self.node_content.get(v).unwrap();
        params.push(new_node)
   }

   node.x = 10// some updates to node
}

}
```

I get
`cannot borrow node_content as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable immutable borrow occurs here`

I tried storing a direct mut reference to node_content outside of self, but then I can't do the calls to the some_function since I've used the self reference.

I *think* RefCells should help here ? But I'm not sure since when I try to use them, I run into the same problem of immutable and mutable references at runtime

```
let node_content = RefCell::new(&mut self.node_content);
for id in list {
   let mut nc = node_content.borrow_mut();
   node = nc.get_mut(id).unwrap();
   
   params=Vec::new()
   for v in node.upstream_nodes() {
        let nc = node_content.borrow(); //~~~thread 'x' panicked at 'already mutably borrowed: BorrowError'
        new_node = nc.get(v).unwrap();
        params.push(new_node)
   }

   node.x = 10// some updates to node
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hold multiple references to different elements inside a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331903/how-to-hold-multiple-references-to-different-elements-inside-a-container)

Comment: Do you need mutable access to `node` within the loop, or only at the end?

Comment: @harmic Only at the end !

Answer (score 1):

From @harmic's suggestion, I can solve this by scoping things right

```
node_content: HashMap<Id, Node<T>>;

pub fn set_val(&mut self,..) {
   for id in self.node_content.iter() {
      self.some_function();
}
...
for id in list {
   {
       node = self.node_content.get(id).unwrap();
   
       params=Vec::new()
       for v in node.upstream_nodes() {
            new_node = self.node_content.get(v).unwrap();
            params.push(new_node)
       }
   }
   node = self.node_content.get_mut(id).unwrap();
   node.x = 10// some updates to node
}

}
```

Is this the most idiomatic option?